# No llama a mi metodo json para cargar un combo en cascada

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas tarde tengo un tema, al cambiar mi combo localidad no se cambia el de barrio, soy nuevo usando ajax, y no entiendo donde esta el problema.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

El código es el siguiente:

En el controlador:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetBarrios(string LocalidadId = "")
    {
        List<Barrios> lBarrios = new List<Barrios>();
        int Id = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(LocalidadId, out Id))
        {
            lBarrios = db.Barrios.Where(a => a.cod_localidad.Equals(Id)).OrderBy(a => a.barrio).ToList();
        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = lBarrios,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "Not valid request",
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet

            };

        }

    }
```

En la vista, este es el jquery:

```
<script  language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#LocalidadId").change(function () {
            //Esto se llama cuando cambia la localidad
            var LocalidadId = parseInt($("#LocalidadId").val());
            if (!isNaN(LocalidadId)) {
                var ddBarrio = $("#BarriosId");
                ddBarrio.empty();
                ddBarrio.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Seleccione un Barrio"));


                //llamamos al controlador
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetBarrios","Home")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { LocalidadId: LocalidadId },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            ddBarrio.append(
                                $("<option></option>").val(val.cod_barrio).html(val.barrio)
                                );
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error!");
                    }


                });
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Y esto en los combos:

```
<div class="form-group" >
        <div label="Localidad" class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownList(Model.Select(a => a.Barrios.cod_localidad).ToString(), @ViewBag.LocalidadId as SelectList, "Localidad")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="frmBarrios">
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownList(Model.Select(w => w.Barrios.cod_barrio).ToString(), ViewBag.BarriosId as SelectList, "Barrio")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @juankGlezz gracias por responder. Se los paso asi a los datos a los combos               List<Localidades> listL = new List<Localidades>();    listL = db.Localidades.OrderBy(a => a.localidad).ToList();     ViewBag.LocalidadId = new SelectList(listL, "cod_localidades", "localidad");

Comment: dentro del `success` pon un `console.log(data)` y en la consola del navegador revisa que estés recibiendo bien el objeto

Comment: No, no recibe nada. No entiendo que puede estar mal. es la primera vez que uso jquery seguro q es un error pavo... Gracias por responder hermano!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetBarrios",{ LocalidadId: LocalidadId }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        ddBarrio.append(
            $("<option></option>").val(val.cod_barrio).html(val.barrio)
        );
    });
});
```

Y tambien haz una prueba poniendo un valor en código duro para `LocalidadId`  y quitando el `if`.

Answer (score 0):

En el controller, cambia estas líneas:

```
return new JsonResult
{
     Data = lBarrios,
     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

Por estas:

```
return Json(new
{
    data = lBarrios
},
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: gracias por responder bro! probe pero no me funciono, lo raro es q pongo puntos de interrupcion y no esta entrando al metodo get del json, no entieno que podria ser.

Comment: Utiliza el depurador del navegador para ver, primero si el selector de jQuery ( $("#LocalidadId") ) está funcionando. Comprueba que el Id de del DropDownList para localidad sea, efectivamente, "LocalidadId".